# Checkbox's checked property binding - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, polymer

I am trying to bind a `Polymer` property to the `CheckBox`'s checked property. However, the property's observer never gets fired, besides, the label also never shows any text.

However, I am able to execute a function every time the `CheckBox` gets clicked.

This is my code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="check-box-example">
  <template>
    <div>
      <label>
        <template if="{{checked}}">Uncheck</template>
        <template if="{{!checked}}">Check</template>
      </label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" on-click="_checkBoxClicked">Check Box
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'check-box-example',
      properties:{
        checked: {
          type: Boolean,
          observer: '_checkedChanged'
        }
      },
      _checkBoxClicked: function() {
        console.log("The Check Box was clicked.");
      },
      _checkedChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("New Checkbox value: " + newValue);
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems:

1. Your templates are missing `is="dom=if"`, so it effectively does nothing in your code.
2. Even with `dom-if` applied, the `if` attribute is set to `checked`, which has no initial value. The binding is only evaluated when the bound property has a non-`undefined` value, and since `checked` is never set, your templates don't stamp any contents (i.e., you wouldn't see "Check" or "Uncheck").

   ```
   properties: {
     checked: {
       type: Boolean,
       value: false  // initial value required for binding
     }
   }
   ```
3. Your template text look backwards. The text content for `if="{{checked}}"` is "Uncheck", while `if="{{!checked}}"` is "Check". Perhaps those are user instructions rather than checkbox status.
4. The native `input` does not emit a change-event for its `checked` attribute, so the binding wouldn't update your `checked` property. Instead, you could update your click-handler to explicitly set your `checked` property to match the value of the `input`'s `checked`.

   ```
   _checkBoxClicked: function(e) { this.checked = this.$.input.checked; }
   ```
5. Your `label` has no association to the `input`, so clicking it doesn't change the state of the `checkbox`. You could fix that by using `label`'s `for`:

   ```
   <label for="foo">...</label>
   <input id="foo">
   ```

   or by making `input` a child of `label`:

   ```
   <label>
     <input>
   </label>
   ```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/kXOoYA?editors=1000)